# Red bean php R::getAll doesn't return any records

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

Here is database structure, generated with red bean php:

```
CREATE TABLE `attrib` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

CREATE TABLE `attrib_photo` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attrib_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UQ_e472845bf988796e2d3eceb91e2745b95f3aa534` (`attrib_id`,`photo_id`),
  KEY `index_for_attrib_photo_attrib_id` (`attrib_id`),
  KEY `index_for_attrib_photo_photo_id` (`photo_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=19 ;


CREATE TABLE `photo` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filepath` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` set('1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `iscolored` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


ALTER TABLE `attrib_photo`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `attrib_photo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`attrib_id`) REFERENCES `attrib` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `attrib_photo_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`photo_id`) REFERENCES `photo` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I'm making manually constructed query:

```
    output of R::debug(); R::getAll($sql);
        select filepath 
        from photo 
        inner join attrib as attrib4 on attrib4.type = 4 and attrib4.value in ("Dmitry") 
        inner join attrib_photo as attrib_photo4 on attrib_photo4.attrib_id = attrib4.id and attrib_photo4.photo_id = photo.id WHERE 1=1 LIMIT 0,25

Array ( ) 
 resultset: 0 rows
 []
```

The result set is empty, but the base contains records, which fall under requirements, and running sql manually in phpMyAdmin shows them.

What's the problem with query, are there any additional debug info I can deal with to solve the problem? Thanks.

**Update:**
A little detail was missing, in original query I used unicode string for photo attribute search. After some investigations I found that php code works correctly and wrong encoding conversion happens on mysql side. Decision was to change collation of whole database to utf8_unicode_ci. Thanks for attention, and sorry for missing info in question.